# How to list all build variants using gradlew?

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

Is it possible to list all build variants using `gradlew` or other command line tool?

For example for the following `build.gradle`:

```
buildTypes {
    debug {}
    release {}
}
productFlavors {
    dev {}
    prod {}
}
```

the command would return something like:

```
devDebug
devRelease
prodDebug
prodRelease
```

---

One option would be to create a gradle task in my `build.gradle` which I would then execute with `gradlew`. But I am looking for a generic solution that would work for any project without the need to add anything.

Comment: can you give more info what u are trying to do, for example are you building script to auto select varaint and build an apk for it ?

Comment: @HossamHassan I am writing a helper script with which I can select multiple variants to build and store in some location and I need the script to be generic and work for all projects.

Answer (score 7):

There isn't a task that outputs all the variants, as far as I know. It wouldn't be terribly hard to create such a task, but I think there may be a better solution for your use-case here.

So you have a few options here. First of all, gradle task are set up in such a way that you would have the following tasks for your example:

```
assemble
assembleDev
assembleProd
assembleDebug
assembleRelease
assembleDevDebug
assembleDevRelease
assembleProdDebug
assembleProdRelease
```

If your goal is to build all variants, then you could simply run `:app:assemble`, and all productFlavor and buildType variants will be built. If you just want release builds, but of each flavor, then you could do `:app:assembleRelease`, and that would automatically run

```
assembleDevRelease
assembleProdRelease
```

Many other tasks follow this same pattern. But not necessarily all of them. So as Stephan mentions in https://stackoverflow.com/a/69254774/2923245, running `:app:tasks` can be a good start to see what tasks you have available.

---

If you really do need a task that outputs each variant name (or you want to access these names in code), then you can do something like this:

```
task("printVariants") {
    doFirst {
        println project.getExtensions().getByType(com.android.build.gradle.AppExtension.class).applicationVariants*.name
    }
}
```

Or, if you want to do something for each variant, then something like:

```
AppExtension android = project.getExtensions().getByType(AppExtension.class)
android.applicationVariants.each { appVariant ->
    // Variant-specific code goes here.
    // Example below: Creating a task for each variant.
    project.tasks.create("${appVariant.name}MyVariantSpecificTask", ...)
}
```

It helps to remember that build.gradle is just code. You can code in whatever here- as long as you get comfortable with Groovy and the gradle + android gradle plugin(AGP) api's.

Answer (score 5):

Gradle already has a task for this, it's called `tasks`

```
./gradlew tasks
```